# Organizing Data across multiple projections

Tags: coordinate-system, file-geodatabase

My department is in the process of migrating data to a more consolidated structured series of GDB's. We are working toward something along the lines of of having 5 different GDB's and placing all of our data in those. For example instead of having multiple one-off GDB's for leasehold we will have it all in one GDB. The issue would be that we have leases in 5 different projection zones (NAD 27 State Plane) thus creating the need to have our GDB in one of those projection zones or having the GDB not have a projection. Then we would just project the MXD's that the data is used in. I am trying to avoid moving a lot of data and then later down the road finding issues with this approach. Are there any issues or a perhaps a better way to approach this issue?

Comment: Why not have a standardised projection across all your data? Then there is no need to have 5 different GDB. You can have 5 feature datasets within a master GDB, all containing different feature classes (point, line, polygon etc)

Comment: Sorry maybe I should have explained that a little better. The 5 different GDB would contain different data like one GDB for Leasehold and another for Infrastructure and another for geology and so on.

Comment: ArcGIS will Project-on-the-fly for most tools. One issue you may encounter is a Transformation, such as projecting Nad27 to Nad83 for example. You can define the correct Transformation, if the default is not to your liking.

Comment: Any interest in storing your data as NAD27 lat/longs instead? Given enough precision, you won't lose any accuracy, and you won't need to worry about the 5 different projection zones. In order to process/work with the data, it will probably need to be projected, but from a data management standpoint, it's easier to handle. Plus you don't have to worry about data straddling two zones and wondering which one it should fall into.

Comment: Is there a like button on this forum? Thank you for all of the replies! I like the idea of the NAD27 projection!